# Read csv from Azure blob Storage and store in a DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to read multiple CSV files from blob storage using python.

The code that I'm using is:

```
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_str)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container)
blobs_list = container_client.list_blobs(folder_root)
for blob in blobs_list:
    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container, blob="blob.name")
    stream = blob_client.download_blob().content_as_text()
```

I'm not sure what is the correct way to store the CSV files read in a pandas dataframe.

I tried to use:

```
df = df.append(pd.read_csv(StringIO(stream)))
```

But this shows me an error.

Any idea how can I to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base on @sahaj-raj-malla [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68620427/12389536):
2 snippets of code to load (or save) file from blob:

1. **shorter** load with pandas [necessary to `pip install adlfs fsspec` ]

```py
import pandas as pd

account_name = "my_account_stage_name"
account_key = "loooooooooooooooooooooong_acccccooooooooount_keeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeey$$$$***$$$$$$$$$$$$$$22222222"
connection_string = f"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={account_name};AccountKey={account_key};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"

pd.read_csv("abfs:///my_container_name/path/to/my/file/on/blob/file.csv", storage_options={"account_name": account_name, "connection_string": connection_string})
```

2. load with pandas & azure [necessary to `pip install azure-storage-blob`]

```py
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import pandas as pd

account_name = "my_account_stage_name"
account_key = "loooooooooooooooooooooong_acccccooooooooount_keeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeey$$$$***$$$$$$$$$$$$$$22222222"
connection_string = f"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={account_name};AccountKey={account_key};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"

# load file from blob
container_name = "my_container_name"
blob_name = "path/to/my/file/on/blob/file.csv"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_name)

# load to RAM, eg. jupyter notebook
pd.read_csv(blob_client.download_blob())

# save file to ROM, eg. local file
local_file_name = "path/to/my/file/on/disk/file.csv"
with open(local_file_name, "wb") as my_blob_locally:
    download_stream = blob_client.download_blob()
    my_blob_locally.write(download_stream.readall())
```

---

How to get **Connections string**

- goto Storage account -> Access Keys -> Show and copy Connection string

Answer (score 10):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('blob_sas_url')
```

The Blob SAS Url can be found by right clicking on the azure portal's blob file that you want to import and selecting Generate SAS. Then, click Generate SAS token and URL button and copy the SAS url to above code in place of blob_sas_url.

Comment: Annoyingly the MS Python SDK is bugged out and you can't do this programmatically from Python. :(

Answer (score 7):

You could download the file from blob storage, then read the data into a pandas DataFrame from the downloaded file.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
import pandas as pd
import tables

STORAGEACCOUNTNAME= <storage_account_name>
STORAGEACCOUNTKEY= <storage_account_key>
LOCALFILENAME= <local_file_name>
CONTAINERNAME= <container_name>
BLOBNAME= <blob_name>

#download from blob
t1=time.time()
blob_service=BlockBlobService(account_name=STORAGEACCOUNTNAME,account_key=STORAGEACCOUNTKEY)
blob_service.get_blob_to_path(CONTAINERNAME,BLOBNAME,LOCALFILENAME)
t2=time.time()
print(("It takes %s seconds to download "+blobname) % (t2 - t1))

# LOCALFILE is the file path
dataframe_blobdata = pd.read_csv(LOCALFILENAME)
```

For more details, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/team-data-science-process/explore-data-blob).

---

If you want to do the conversion directly, the code will help. You need to get content from the blob object and in the `get_blob_to_text` there's no need for the local file name.

```
from io import StringIO
blobstring = blob_service.get_blob_to_text(CONTAINERNAME,BLOBNAME).content
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(blobstring))
```

Comment: `from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService` no longer works on the latest Python SDK; it's legacy now.

Answer (score 4):

You can now directly read from BlobStorage into a Pandas DataFrame:

```
mydata = pd.read_csv(
        f"abfs://{blob_path}",
        storage_options={
            "connection_string": os.environ["STORAGE_CONNECTION"]
    })
```

where `blob_path` is the path to your file, given as `{container-name}/{blob-preifx.csv}`

Comment: And what goes into "STORAGE_CONNECTION"?

Comment: @JoshuaStafford that would be the connection string for the blob storage. You will find this key in the Azure Portal: Go to your Resource Group, then your Storage Account and in then click on Access Keys under Security & Networking. There you will have "Connection String"

Comment: @user3778817 I tried this on .sav files, pd.read_spss(), but didn't work. Does it only works for csv files?

Comment: Looks like you probably need to install fsspec and adlfs from pip

Answer (score 2):

The BlockBlobService as part of azure-storage is deprecated. Use below instead:

```
!pip install azure-storage-blob
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import pandas as pd

STORAGEACCOUNTURL= <storage_account_url>
STORAGEACCOUNTKEY= <storage_account_key>
LOCALFILENAME= <local_file_name>
CONTAINERNAME= <container_name>
BLOBNAME= <blob_name>

#download from blob
blob_service_client_instance=BlobServiceClient(account_url=STORAGEACCOUNTURL, credential=STORAGEACCOUNTKEY)
blob_client_instance = blob_service_client_instance.get_blob_client(CONTAINERNAME, BLOBNAME, snapshot=None)
with open(LOCALFILENAME, "wb") as my_blob:
    blob_data = blob_client_instance.download_blob()
    blob_data.readinto(my_blob)

#import blob to dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(LOCALFILENAME)
```

LOCALFILENAME is the same as BLOBNAME

Comment: Is it a typo re 'DataFrame' ?

Answer (score 1):

BlockBlobService is indeed deprecated. However, @Deepak's answer doesn't work for me. Below works:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

CONNECTION_STRING= <connection_string>
CONTAINERNAME= <container_name>
BLOBNAME= <blob_name>

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(CONNECTION_STRING)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(CONTAINERNAME)
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(BLOBNAME)

with BytesIO() as input_blob:
    blob_client.download_blob().download_to_stream(input_blob)
    input_blob.seek(0)
    df = pd.read_csv(input_blob)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **blob_client** to read the file as text and use that text as input to pandas `read_csv()` method. For Example

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from azure.identity import InteractiveBrowserCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, ContainerClient

# name of the file 
file_name = 'sample_file.csv' 
# Note:- include folders if you have a folder structure in the blob 
# container ex: -> main/child/sample.csv

# storage account URL
STORAGE_ACCOUNT_URL = 'https://sampleblob.blob.core.windows.net'
# name of the container that holds your CSV file
BLOB_STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME = "sample-storage-container"
# Here I am using the interactive credential, you may use any other credential
CREDENTIAL = InteractiveBrowserCredential()

# Create the BlobServiceClient object
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(STORAGE_ACCOUNT_URL, credential=CREDENTIAL)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container=BLOB_STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME)
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(file_name)
if blob_client.exists() # check if blob exists
    download_stream = blob_client.download_blob() # read file
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(download_stream.content_as_text())) # use text as input to pandas
    print(f"Shape of File {file_name} is {df.shape}")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using AzureML, there is an easier solution with datastores. An AzureML datastore automatically handles authentication to Azure storage without exposing credentials in notebooks. They can also do identity-based authentication.

First, you construct a datastore URI - a path to the data:

```py
# Azure Machine Learning workspace details:
subscription = '<subscription_id>'
resource_group = '<resource_group>'
workspace = '<workspace>'
datastore_name = '<datastore>'
path_on_datastore '<path>'

# long-form Datastore uri format:
uri = f'azureml://subscriptions/{subscription}/resourcegroups/{resource_group}/workspaces/{workspace}/datastores/{datastore_name}/paths/{path_on_datastore}'
```

Then just plug into Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv(uri)
```

It is worth mentioning that you can use this without needing the compute to be AzureML-based - for example, you can leverage the above using a local machine (laptop). You need to have installed in your python environment, the `azureml-fsspec` Python library:

```bash
pip install azureml-fsspec
```

Other frameworks such as PyTorch can also natively handle `azureml://` URIs.

For more information, read [Access data from Azure cloud storage during interactive development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-access-data-interactive?view=azureml-api-2)

Answer (score 0):

Sahaj has a good answer using a SAS URL, but it's better to generate the URL dynamically in Python IMO if you will be doing this a lot for different blobs. You can do that like so:

```py
import datetime

import pandas as pd
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobPrefix, generate_blob_sas

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
ACCOUNT_NAME = "blob-account-name"
STORAGEACCOUNTURL = f"https://{ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net/"
CONTAINERNAME = "container-name"
blob_filepath = "path/to/blob.csv"
permission = "r"  # for read-only permissions; see docs on generate_blob_sas for other options
blob_service_client_instance = BlobServiceClient(account_url=STORAGEACCOUNTURL, credential=credential)

container_client = self.blob_service_client_instance.get_container_client(container=CONTAINERNAME)

expiry = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)

user_delegation_key = self.blob_service_client_instance.get_user_delegation_key(key_start_time=datetime.datetime.now(), key_expiry_time=expiry)

sas_str = generate_blob_sas(ACCOUNT_NAME, CONTAINERNAME, blob_filepath, user_delegation_key=user_delegation_key, expiry=expiry, permission=permission)

url = f"https://{ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net/{CONTAINERNAME}/{blob_filepath}?{sas_str}"

df = pd.read_csv(url)

# or using polars
import polars as pl

df = pl.read_csv(url)
```

If you want to use a storage account key instead, the sas_str is generated like:

```py
sas_str = generate_blob_sas(ACCOUNT_NAME, CONTAINERNAME, filepath, account_key=STORAGEACCOUNTKEY, expiry=expiry, permission=permission)
```