# Trouble reading Blob Storage File into Azure ML Notebook

Tags: pandas, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have an Excel file uploaded to my ML workspace.

I can access the file as an azure FileDataset object. However, I don't know how to get it into a pandas DataFrame since 'FileDataset' object has no attribute 'to_dataframe'.

Azure ML notebooks seem to make a point of avoiding pandas for some reason.

Does anyone know how to get blob files into pandas dataframes from within Azure ML notebooks?

Comment: Related: [Read csv from Azure blob Storage and store in a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62670991/15497888)

Answer (score 1):

To explore and manipulate a dataset, it must first be downloaded from the blob source to a local file, which can then be loaded in a pandas DataFrame.

Here are the steps to follow for this procedure:

1. Download the data from Azure blob with the following Python code sample using Blob service. Replace the variable in the following code with your specific values:

   ```
   from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
   import pandas as pd

   STORAGEACCOUNTURL= <storage_account_url>
   STORAGEACCOUNTKEY= <storage_account_key>
   LOCALFILENAME= <local_file_name>
   CONTAINERNAME= <container_name>
   BLOBNAME= <blob_name>

   #download from blob
   t1=time.time()
   blob_service_client_instance = 
   BlobServiceClient(account_url=STORAGEACCOUNTURL, 
   credential=STORAGEACCOUNTKEY)
   blob_client_instance = 
   blob_service_client_instance.get_blob_client(CONTAINERNAME, BLOBNAME, 
   snapshot=None)
   with open(LOCALFILENAME, "wb") as my_blob:
   blob_data = blob_client_instance.download_blob()
   blob_data.readinto(my_blob)
   t2=time.time()
   print(("It takes %s seconds to download "+BLOBNAME) % (t2 - t1))
   ```
2. Read the data into a pandas DataFrame from the downloaded file.

   ```
   #LOCALFILE is the file path
   dataframe_blobdata = pd.read_csv(LOCALFILENAME)
   ```

For more details you can follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/data-science-process/explore-data-blob#load-the-data-into-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use storage SDKs for this. AzureML datastores can handle authentication (both identity and credentials. In the case of credentials, you won't expose the keys).

You can create a URI to the path with:

```py
# Azure Machine Learning workspace details:
subscription = '<subscription_id>'
resource_group = '<resource_group>'
workspace = '<workspace>'
datastore_name = '<datastore>'
path_on_datastore '<path>'

# long-form Datastore uri format:
uri = f'azureml://subscriptions/{subscription}/resourcegroups/{resource_group}/workspaces/{workspace}/datastores/{datastore_name}/paths/{path_on_datastore}'
```

You then plug that path directly into pandas

```py
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv(uri)
```

More docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-access-data-interactive?view=azureml-api-2