# Read straming data from Azure Blob storage into Databricks

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks

I'm trying to read files from an blob storage in databricks, make some computation through dataframe and write the dataframe on cassandra. At the moment file are of **append blob** type storage so, like said in the documentation page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/data-sources/wasb-check-blob-types, I cannot mount those in the DBFS.

When working on the local machine I'm able to download it through the Azure Storage SDK for Python, but if I try to do same thing on databricks I receve the following error:

> Unable to stream download: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')", ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

the code I'm running is the following

```
file_dir = data.strftime("%Y%m")
file_name = data.strftime("%Y%m%d") + ".csv"

local_path = f"dbfs:/FileStore/{file_dir}"
local_file = f"{local_path}/{file_name}"
blob_name = f"{file_dir}/{file_name}"

blob_service_client_instance = BlobServiceClient(account_url="https://"+STORAGEACCOUNTURL+".blob.core.windows.net", credential=STORAGEACCOUNTKEY)
blob_client_instance = blob_service_client_instance.get_blob_client(CONTAINERNAME, blob_name, snapshot=None)

with open(local_file, "wb") as my_blob:
           blob_data = blob_client_instance.download_blob(max_concurrency=10)
           blob_data.readinto(my_blob)
```

on the other note if I try to write it not in *dbfs:/FileStore/{file_dir}* but in the working category of databricks using *os.getcwd()* I'm able to write it, but not able to read the file (and probably reading from here could be a good workaround).

Comment: Please refer the same issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/24636 need to update your azure-storage-blob =12.14.0.

Comment: I strangely succeded one time (with anser below), but after that I received the same error, even after updating the azure-storage-blob to the 12.14.0

Answer (score 1):

Changed approach and streamed the file directly into a dataframe. The answer was due to this post [Read csv from Azure blob Storage and store in a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62670991/read-csv-from-azure-blob-storage-and-store-in-a-dataframe), the answer from "lsl__".

```
from io import BytesIO
import pandas as pd

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url="https://"+STORAGEACCOUNTURL+".blob.core.windows.net", credential=STORAGEACCOUNTKEY)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(CONTAINERNAME)
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_name)

                
with BytesIO() as input_blob:
  blob_client.download_blob().download_to_stream(input_blob)
  input_blob.seek(0)
  df = pd.read_csv(input_blob)
```